# How to select a particular element from json array

Tags: postgresql

I have a 'notifications' table with a column 'dest_user_id_arr' as json with the following value:

```
id                     dest_user_id_arr
1                      {"users":[83,84,85]}
2                      {"users":[89,83,92]}
3                      {"users":[87,88,83]}
```

I would like to select those id where user is 83.

Comment: Please tag your PostgreSQL version. Is it a JSON or a JSONB column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the type is jsonb, Use the jsonb containment operator:

```
SELECT * FROM notifications n WHERE dest_user_id_arr @> '{"users":[83]}';
```

If the type is json or text, either change it to jsonb, or (if you don't care about performance) dynamically cast it.

```
SELECT * FROM notifications n WHERE dest_user_id_arr::jsonb @> '{"users":[83]}';
```

Answer (score 0):

IF column is json:

```
 SELECT id 
  FROM notifications n
  WHERE json_array_elements(n.dest_user_id_arr->'users') = 83;
```

If column is jsonb:

```
 SELECT id 
  FROM notifications n
  WHERE jsonb_array_elements(n.dest_user_id_arr->'users') = 83;
```

Comment: "ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE"